# updating value and displaying the value on existing select option

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

first,I have table display from database, in each row it has update button.
second, i have a four (4) collapsible select option form.
third, the select option form has value from database. this value is also present in the column on the table above(first).

Now what i want is when i update the value from the row on the table, the collapsible form will open then the value from the table will display on the select option form. 
Here's my code. the code below cant open the collapsible form and display the value on the select option form.

displaytable.php

```
<?php
$output='';
$noresult='';                                       

if (isset($_POST['search'])) 
{
$globalpid = $_POST['search'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transaction where patientid ='$globalpid' order by trandate asc") or die ("could not search");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);    

$globalpid = mysql_real_escape_string($globalpid);
if($count == '' && $countname==0)
{ 
?>
<?php require_once 'search.php'; ?>
<div class="container" style="padding-left:30px">                           
<br><p><font color="#0B3861"><?php echo "There was no search results!"; ?>  </font> 
</div>
</div> 
<?php   }else{          
?>
<?php
$total = '';
$add=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(tranamount) from transaction where patientid = $globalpid");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($add))
{
$totalamount=$row['SUM(tranamount)'];
}
require_once 'transactionheadermenu.php';
?>
<div class="container" style="padding-top:0px; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px;">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><font color="#2B547E"><?php echo "$outputname";?></font></h3></div>
<div class="panel-body">
<?php require_once 'billpatientquery.php';?>
<?php
echo "<table class='table table-hover';>
<tr>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='145px' align='center'>Patient ID</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='145px' align='center'>Date</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='600px' align='center'>Item / Description</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='90px' align='center'>Quantity</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='90px' align='center'>Price</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='150px' align='center'>Amount</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='30px' align='center'>Update</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='30px' align='center'>Delete</td>

</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
echo "
<tr>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='145px' align='center'>".$row['patientid']."</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='145px' align='center'>".$row['trandate']."</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='600px'>".$row['trandescription']."</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='90px' align='center'>".$row['tranquantity']."</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='90px' align='right'>".number_format($row['tranunitprice'],2)."</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='150px' align='right'>".number_format($row['tranamount'],2)."</td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray'><a href='updatebillindex.php?update=$row[id]'>update</a></td>
<td style='border:1px solid; color:gray'><button class='btn btn-default btn-sm';><a href='updatebillindex.php?update=$row[0]'>edit
 <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></button></td>
</tr> ";
}
echo "</table>";    
?>  
</div>

</div>
</div>
<?php   }
} ?>
```

updatebillindex.php

```
?php
        if (isset($_GET['update'])) 
        //              
        {
        $id = $_GET['update'];
        //      //$tranid = $_POST['update'];
        //$patientid = $_POST['update'];
        //$trandate = $_POST['update'];
        //$getname = $_POST['update'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transaction where id = '$id'") or die ("could not search");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);    

        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        $id = $rows['id'];
        $tranid = $rows['tranid'];
        $trandate = $rows['trandate'];
        $patientid = $rows['patientid'];
        $transactiontype = $rows['transactiontype'];
        $trandescription = $rows['trandescription'];
        $tranquantity = $rows['tranquantity'];
        $tranunitprice = $rows['tranunitprice'];
        $tranamount =$rows['tranamount'];
        $gettrandescription = $rows['trandescription'];

        }
        }

        if (isset($_POST['selectmedicine'])) {

        $gettrandescription=$_POST['medicineid'];   
        }

        if (isset($_POST['selectroomquantity'])) {

        $tranquantity=$_POST['quantity'];
        }

        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#collapseone').collapseone({
        toggle: true
        });
        </script>
        <option value="<?php echo $trandescription; ?>" <?php if($trandescription==$gettrandescription){ echo "selected";} ?> ><?php echo $gettrandescription; ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $tranquantity; ?>" <?php if($tranquantity==$tranquantity){ echo "selected";} ?> ><?php echo $tranquantity; ?></option>

        <form action="billindex.php" method="POST">

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo "$id"; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="tranid" value="<?php echo "$tranid"; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="patientid" value="<?php echo "$patientid"; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="trandate" value="<?php echo "$trandate"; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="transactiontype" value="<?php echo "$transactiontype"; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="trandescription" value="<?php echo "$trandescription"; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="tranquanity" value="<?php echo "$tranquantity"; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="tranunitprice" value="<?php echo "$tranunitprice"; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="tranamount" value="<?php echo "$tranamount"; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">

        </form>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Medicine
        </a>
        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="transaction.php" method="POST">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h7>Medicine Type : </h7></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <select name="selectmedicine" class="form-control col-sm-4" id="medicinename">
        <option id="0" style="width:100px"></option>
        <?php

        $medicine = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM medicine");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($medicine)) {
        echo '<option id="' . $row['medicinename']  . '"';
        echo ' value="' . $row['medicineid'] . '"';
        if($row['medicineid'] == $row['medicinename']) {
        echo ' selected="selected"'; 
        }
        echo '>';
        echo $row['medicinename'];
        echo '</option>';               
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>          

        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading panel-height:20px":><h7>Quantity : </h7></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <select name="selectmedicinequantity" class="form-control col-md-4" id="quantityname">
        <option id="0" style="width:100px"></option>

        <?php

        $medicinequantity = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quantity");
        while ($displayquantity = mysql_fetch_array($medicinequantity)) {
        $quantityid = $displayquantity['id'];
        $quantityname = $displayquantity['quantityname'];
        //$quantityprice = $displayquantity['quantityprice'];
        ?>

        <option id=" <?php echo $displayquantity['quantityid']; ?>"><?php if($displayquantity['quantityid'] == $displayquantity['quantityname']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?><?php echo $displayquantity['quantityname'] ?></option>

        <?php 
        }
        ?>

        </select>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: this is weird `if($row['medicineid'] == $row['medicinename']) {echo ' selected="selected"'; }` and never seen anything like this `<option id="' . $row['medicinename']  . '"';`

Comment: hi shehary, actually that code works. it display the medicine name column from the database.

Comment: @Shehary it isn't weird at all. The first part is just a shortcut of doing an IF statement and doing different things for each case. The id part is even more common.

Comment: @mfisher91 it's weird in sense that id==name fetching from same table but anyhow I'm not the one with the code and OP said it's working great so may be not that weird

Comment: @Romeo after reading the question, your code is working properly but what you want is that when you update values in database the form will open with updated values from database and values show in `select` dropdown ?

Comment: correction on the pages name above.

@shehary partly yes, the collapsible form will open and display the value on select option form and select other value on the option then click the button to save the preferred value in the database.

Comment: the display table is working, when i click the update link, all the values  on the rows displays in the hidden input (working), the script code does not open collapsible form and the two <option> below the script displays the medicine name and the quantity value but not on the select option form.

Comment: `updatebillindex.php` you are posting form but why `if (isset($_GET['update']))` why not `if (isset($_POST['update']))` and on same page after script you are missing `<select>` you have close the `<option>` inside `<select>` and to which HTML element this binds `#collapseone`

Comment: $_GET is to get the rows from table, for update and to be displayed in the hidden input and that is working but when i change it to POST is does not.

Comment: collapseone is from the aria-controls="collapseone". I have 4 collapsible  form 1. is room, has two form (roomtype & quantity) 2. medicine, has two form(medicinename and quantity) 3. laboratory and 4. professional, each has two form inside.

Comment: ok but cant see any HTML which binds with ``$('#collapseone')` ` and this `<option value="<?php echo $trandescription; ?>" <?php if($trandescription==$gettrandescription){ echo "selected";} ?> ><?php echo $gettrandescription; ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $tranquantity; ?>" <?php if($tranquantity==$tranquantity){ echo "selected";} ?> ><?php echo $tranquantity; ?></option>` there is no `<select>` tag

Comment: the two <option> has value result, medicinename and quantity, and echoed/display along the page, what i want is these two values supposed to be displayed on the select option so that i can the change the value which is the value came from the database also,

Comment: for example, i have two columns in the database, the id and the name. in common update practice, when i click the link/button to update the name. this name will be displayed on the text box, the common thing. in my thing, the name will be displayed on the select option. so that i can change the name listed in the database displayed thru select option. sorry my english is not that good. hehehe